# Common Lisp program error

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Im pretty new in Lisp programming language and I got an error that I can't fix :/
Hope someone can help me. (Sorry if it's a newbie mistake)

Here's my code:

```
(defun inicia()
(princ "Ingresa la infija")
(setf temp(read-line))
(setf final nil)
(setf pilatemp nil)
(setf tamaño (length temp))
(setf cont 0)
(loop 
    (setf cadena (reverse temp))
    (if (= cont tamaño) (return ))
    (setf caracter (string (char temp cont)))
    (if (= (operando caracter) 1) (push caracter final))
    (if (= (operador caracter) 1) (PROGN (loop 
                                            (if (and (= cont tamaño) (<= (jerarquia caracter) (jerarquia (first pilatemp)))) (return))
                                                (push (first pilatemp) final)
                                                (pop pilatemp)
                                                (setf cont (+ cont 1))))
                                        (push caracter pilatemp)))
    (if (equal caracter ")") (push caracter pilatemp))
    (if (equal caracter "(") (PROGN (loop
                                        (if (string= (first pila) ")") (return))
                                        (push (pop pilatemp) final))
                                    (pop pilatemp)))
    (setf cont (+ cont 1)))
(loop 
    (setf tamaño (length pilatemp))
    (if (<= tamaño 0) (return))
    (if (equal (first pilatemp) ")") (pop pilatemp) (push (pop pilatemp) final))
    (setf final (reverse final))))
(defun jerarquia(operan)
    (cond 
        ((string/= operan "^") 8)
        ((string/= operan "$") 8)
        ((string/= operan "*") 7)
        ((string/= operan "/") 6)
        ((string/= operan "+") 5)
        ((string/= operan "-") 4)
        ((string/= operan "(") 3)
        ((string/= operan ")") 2)
        ((string/= operan "=") 1)
        (T 0)))
(defun operando (operan)
    (cond 
        ((= (operador operan) 0) 1)
        ;ojo con el retorno del siguiente if
        ((string/= operan "(") 1)
        ((string/= operan ")") 1)
        (T 0)))
(defun operador (operan)
    (cond
        ((string/= operan "+") 1)
        ((string/= operan "-") 1)
        ((string/= operan "*") 1)
        ((string/= operan "/") 1)
        ((string/= operan "^") 1)
        ((string/= operan "$") 1)
        ((string/= operan "=") 1)
        (T 0)))
```

And the error I'm getting is the next one:

```
-SETQ: variable PILATEMP has no value
```

Thanks :)

Comment: please format your code properly and use `let` to bind variables.

Comment: Downvote because of poor code formatting.

Comment: Please listen to sds's advice and use `let` to introduce local variables. Using `setf` for this purpose is undefined behavior. Also, for clarity you should use `when` instead of `if` if you don't have an alternative branch in a conditional, particularly if you need to wrap the consequent branch in `progn` because `when` does that automatically.

Comment: I'm sorry for the code formatting.. I'm learning by myself so I try to link every function I find in Lisp to C++,Java or C functions. I'll change it right away :) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this error because of one closing parenthesis too many:

```
  (setf cont (+ cont 1)) ; <--- you had 3 closing parentheses here
  (loop 
    (setf tamaño (length pilatemp))
    (if (<= tamaño 0) (return))
    (if (equal (first pilatemp) ")") (pop pilatemp) (push (pop pilatemp) final))
    (setf final (reverse final))))
```

so the loop got executed at the top level, and not inside the function.